# How can I add an app tab to my facebook page?

Tags: facebook, tabs

Since a few days I can't add app tabs to pages anymore. The options to view the app page and then click on add to my page have disappeared. Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has changed since a few weeks, now you have to call an URL like this:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

Replace YOUR_APP_ID with the ID of the App, and YOUR_URL with the URL the App is running in - keep in mind this has to be a correct and existing URL!

Comment: and as far as I know, the url must match the specified domains in your app options

Comment: I've been searching for a way to do this and just found your answer. Is this documented somewhere? Why is it so hard to figure out how to do this?

Comment: Yeah, its very stupid for Facebook to hide such a thing. Here is their explanation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: Thanks for this answer